# Does WordNet only contains Lemmas?

Tags: reference-request, wordnet, lemmas

It seems to be an implicit assumption that wordnet only contains lemmas.
Eg in [Combine dictionary lemmatization with stemmer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9529/combine-dictionary-lemmatization-with-stemmer).

I feel confidant it is a correct one, the Wordnet interface refers to lemmas.

However neither in the wordnet paper[1](http://mooo.cf/20140731/Reference/1995%20-%20Miller%20-%20WordNet%20a%20lexical%20database%20for%20English.pdf), nor in the 5 Papers on WordNet [2](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/5papers.pdf),[3](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/235.full.pdf),[4](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/245.full.pdf),[5](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/265.full.pdf),[6](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/278.full.pdf),[7](https://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Rehu8OOzMIMC&oi=fnd&pg=PA105&dq=Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20WordNet%20Lexical%20Database%20and%20Searching%20Software&ots=IqjdQjWRc4&sig=1NMSarjTCLLMe9HYDcJAHEpqUMA#v=onepage&q=Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20WordNet%20Lexical%20Database%20and%20Searching%20Software&f=false) mention the word "lemma" at all.

I am starting to have my doubts.
I am looking for a high quality cite-able source to reassure my doubts.
Or to correct my misunderstanding.

#### Referenes:

- [1](http://mooo.cf/20140731/Reference/1995%20-%20Miller%20-%20WordNet%20a%20lexical%20database%20for%20English.pdf) [Miller, G. A. WordNet: a lexical database for English Communications of the ACM, ACM, 1995, 38, 39-41][1](http://mooo.cf/20140731/Reference/1995%20-%20Miller%20-%20WordNet%20a%20lexical%20database%20for%20English.pdf)
- [2](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/5papers.pdf) [All 5 Papers][2](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/5papers.pdf)
- [3](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/235.full.pdf) [Miller, George A., et al. "Introduction to wordnet: An on-line lexical database*." International journal of lexicography 3.4 (1990): 235-244.][3](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/235.full.pdf)
- [4](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/245.full.pdf) [Miller, George A. "Nouns in WordNet: a lexical inheritance system." International journal of Lexicography 3.4 (1990): 245-264.][4](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/245.full.pdf)
- [5](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/265.full.pdf) [Gross, Derek, and Katherine J. Miller. "Adjectives in wordnet." International Journal of Lexicography 3.4 (1990): 265-277.][5](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/265.full.pdf)
- [6](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/278.full.pdf) [Fellbaum, Christiane. "English verbs as a semantic net." International Journal of Lexicography 3.4 (1990): 278-301.][6](http://ijl.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/278.full.pdf)
- [7](https://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Rehu8OOzMIMC&oi=fnd&pg=PA105&dq=Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20WordNet%20Lexical%20Database%20and%20Searching%20Software&ots=IqjdQjWRc4&sig=1NMSarjTCLLMe9HYDcJAHEpqUMA#v=onepage&q=Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20WordNet%20Lexical%20Database%20and%20Searching%20Software&f=false) [Tengi, Randee I. "Design and implementation of the WordNet lexical database and searching software." Fellbaum, Christiane (réd.), WordNet: an electronic lexical database, The MIT Press, Cambridge, Massachusetts (1998): 105.][7](https://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Rehu8OOzMIMC&oi=fnd&pg=PA105&dq=Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20WordNet%20Lexical%20Database%20and%20Searching%20Software&ots=IqjdQjWRc4&sig=1NMSarjTCLLMe9HYDcJAHEpqUMA#v=onepage&q=Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20WordNet%20Lexical%20Database%20and%20Searching%20Software&f=false)

Comment: Reference 5, does mention lexemes but not in a clear context that sayins wordnet only contains lexemes.

Comment: Do you have any real reason to doubt that? Why would WordNet use anything by lemmas? Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reference:

> In WordNet only the base forms of words are generally represented. 
>   ... 
>   [With regards to phrases] In general, only the base forms of words, even those making up compounds such as *attorney general*, are stored in WordNet

from:

The chapter: 
*Design and implementation of the WordNet lexical database and searching software*, by Tengi, R. I.

From page 105 of the  book: 
Massachusetts Design and implementation of the WordNet lexical database and searching software, *Fellbaum, Christiane (réd.), WordNet: an electronic lexical database, The MIT Press, Cambridge, Massachusetts,* **1998**

Here, *base form* is used as a synonym for *reference form* (as is printed in the section heading in a dictionary), and as wordnet defined lemma: "the heading that indicates the subject of an annotation or a literary composition or a dictionary entry".